# Is it possible to access a smartphone's API on Raspberry PI via cabled connection?

Tags: android, python, linux, camera, raspberry-pi

For my company, we need a device to take pictures locally and store it locally as well. There are no internet or wireless connections available within this machine. This is an industrial setting where the machines (and so its control components/sensors) move a lot.

I have written an algorithm that requires images as inputs, and maps them to output values used for control commands. However, we now need to interface this software, with the appropriate hardware (camera plus computer/microcontroller) to test and use this algorithm.

Online research suggests that there are plenty of idustrial cameras with addionial software/SDKs supplied for programmable use on an arbitrary OS. However, because of our space and mechanical constraints for the camera (must fit within ~100 mm in 1 direction, must be water resistant etc.), it becomes very hard to find the right camera that fits.

Because of these limitations, our current idea is to use an (industrial) smartphone, which also yields some supplementary advantages (like additional sensors, which may be used for different applications later on). The smartphone is then connected via cable (depending on the connector a usb-c or micro-usb etc.) to a raspberry pi. We are flexible in the exact types of hardware. For example, we can buy a linux smarthpone if required, or we can use a different computer/microcontroller if needed. So the answer to this question may suggest different smartphone type and computer type if necessary.

Our current available hardware is an android smartphone and raspberry pi 2 though.
And my question, based on the above assumptions, is:

**Is there some software/method available that enables the Raspberry Pi to access a smartphone's camera (and potentially other sensors) such that you can control it to capture images?**

The preferred programming language of use is Python, but I imagine that other languages may be required for such task.

An online search reveals that usually people look to do it the other way around: They either seek to [control the Pi with their smartphone](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/walk-through-and-tutorial-on-how-to-connect-the-raspberry-pi-and-mobile-phone-connect-raspberry-pi-mobiletablet/), or they  [access the camera wirelessly](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-access-your-raspberry-pi-camera-from-anywhere-544ab9e5bacc).

---

If anything is unclear, please suggest improvements/addtions and I will edit the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you write a small app for this that connects to a webserver / API running on your Raspberry PI. The app will listen to commands from the webserver / API and execute what it is instructed to do (e.g. Take a picture and send it).

Because there is no connectivity out of the box (as you said), you can enable tethering via USB on the smartphone, and by connecting the smartphone to the Raspberry PI using the USB cable (and installing the required drivers) they will have internet connectivity to eachother, and the app will be able to communicate directly to the webserver / API on the Raspberry PI.

[EDIT] You could also use a USB webcam. The smartphone will be connected via USB as well, so you could just use a USB webcam directly. Find one that is waterproof, or a rugged one, and just communicate with the webcam directly from the Raspberry PI instead of having to write an app in between (which will greatly increase development costs). This method will also be cheaper in terms of hardware

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about something in this direction as well. I'm probably gonna have to try this at some point. I'm hoping for some existing tools though but it's looking like I might have no other choice.

Comment: Yes indeed, too bad about the constraints that force you to use a smartphone. Might be a stupid question, but did you take a look at [a camera module that is directly interfacable with the Raspeberry PI](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/raspberry-pi-camera-en-accessoires)?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. No, not in detail. The problem with these modules is that the raspberry pi will be in a different enclosed location within the machine, and the camera (module) should be mounted on a specific place, where it is exposed to environmental conditions (e.g. rain). I might have not mentioned this clearly in my q. Also, if you were to somewow combine them both into the same placement, it would be hard to make water resistent. Good thinking though

Comment: I understand. But now that you mentioned it, why not use a USB webcam? The smartphone will be connected via USB as well, so you could just use a USB webcam directly. Find one that is waterproof, or a rugged one, and just communicate with the webcam directly from the Raspberry PI instead of having to write an app in between (which will greatly increase development costs). This method will also be cheaper in terms of hardware.

Comment: Hmm good suggestion. Now that you mention it, we may have done something in the pas with a camera as [such.](https://www.oemoffhighway.com/electronics/sensors/proximity-detection-safety-systems/asset-management-safety-systems/product/12165587/orlaco-inc-orlaco-emos-camera) I will discuss it with my colleagues.

Comment: Great! If you think the options I proposed cover most of the acceptable possibilities, would you maybe consider accepting my answer?